# How can i get actual path of the docx file uploaded to the database using django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-docx

I am developing a simple web application using django that can take three .docx files containing tables and merge those tables in a single file and return that file to user in downloadable form. I used python-docx library for docx file processing. All three files are uploaded successfully without having any issue but the problem arises when i try to open those document files using `doc.Document(file path)` constructor of docx library. But the problem is that doc.Document() can't open the word file and it shows error like `docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at '/media/documents/word/SS_SMS39_CE3_InQfp7c.docx'`  while it clearly shows the path and while checking on the /media/documents... i can clearly locate that file. I tried a lot on searching about this issue went through docx documentation and even django's fileStorage documentations. But i cannot solve this problem. If you could help me figure out this issue, i will be grateful. I have provided all the models.py, views.py, urls.py, and my templates

```
models.py
from django.db import models
class Mydocument(models.Model):
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/word/')
    file2 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/word/')
    file3 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/word/')
    file_processed = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/word/',null=True,default='documents/word/ssm.docx')
```

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import DocumentForm
from .models import Mydocument
import docx as dc
def SS_Merge(response, n, f1,f2,f3):
    file = Mydocument.objects.get(id=n)

    merged_url = file.file_processed.url
    print(merged_url)
    #doc = dc.Document(merged_url)
    doc1 = dc.Document(f1)
    doc2 = dc.Document(f2)
    doc3 = dc.Document(f3)
    ##Some Code for performing all the file processing logic and Merging them.
    doc.save('ss merged.docx')
    #Trying to update the file at database with the new one"
    return render(response, 'download.html', {'file': file})


def home(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(response.POST, response.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_doc= form.save()
            file1_name = new_doc.file1.url
            file2_name = new_doc.file2.url
            file3_name = new_doc.file3.url

            number =new_doc.pk
            print(number)
            print("url",file2_name)
            print("url",file1_name)
            SS_Merge(response,number,file1_name,file2_name,file3_name)
            #return redirect('home')

            print("Sucessful Fileupload")
            #return render(response, 'download.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(response,'upload.html',{'form':form})
```

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/',include('myapp.urls') ),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

```
Settings.py
#Other Things
TATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/static/')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

```
upload.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h2> Upload Three SS Files Here..</h2>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile01" name="file1">
  <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload</label>
   </div>
        <br/>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile03" name="file2">
  <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload</label>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile02" name="file3">
  <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload</label>
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</div>
    </form>
        <h5> Hit Merge to merge all three files</h5>


{% endblock %}
```

```
download.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1> SS-Merge Successful!!</h1>
    <br/>
    <h2> Click Download to Get  your Merged SS</h2>
    <br/>
    <a href="{{ file.file_processed.url }}" class = "btn btn-secondary btn-sm" target="_blank"> Download Docx</a>
    <br/>


</div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: did you configure your settings.py files for static files ?

Comment: Yes, I have configuerd it like ```STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/static/')
] ```

Comment: I think there should not be any issue in my setting.py configuration as i am able to upload the file successfully. I feel like i am missing something but could not figured it out because i am a beginner in django.